# QT QLabel setPixmap from QAbstractVideoSurface

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel, qcamera

I'm implementing my own class for probing video frames from QCamera under windows. It's a subclass of QAbstractVideoSurface. So, my probe generates QPixmap which I tried to draw on QLabel (as viewfinder). And I've got segmentation fault on QLabel setPixmap call.

I'm sure my Qpixmap is well made, because I can save it on the disk with a save(). My QLabel is inititalized and works well, because I can load QPixmap from the disk and set it to QLabel. I guess there is problem with a format of a pixmap, but can't clue how to correct it :(

My code

frameprobe.h

```
#ifndef FRAMEPROBE_H
#define FRAMEPROBE_H
#include <QAbstractVideoSurface>
#include <QList>
#include <QPixmap>

class FrameProbe : public QAbstractVideoSurface
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit FrameProbe(QObject *parent = 0);

        QList<QVideoFrame::PixelFormat> supportedPixelFormats(QAbstractVideoBuffer::HandleType handleType) const;

        bool present(const QVideoFrame &frame);

    signals:
        void frameAvailable(QImage frame);
        void frameReady(QPixmap frame);

    public slots:
};

#endif // FRAMEPROBE_H
```

frameprobe.cpp

```
#include "frameprobe.h"

FrameProbe::FrameProbe(QObject *parent) :
    QAbstractVideoSurface(parent)
{
}

QList<QVideoFrame::PixelFormat> FrameProbe::supportedPixelFormats(QAbstractVideoBuffer::HandleType handleType) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(handleType);
    return QList<QVideoFrame::PixelFormat>()
        << QVideoFrame::Format_ARGB32
        << QVideoFrame::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied
        << QVideoFrame::Format_RGB32
        << QVideoFrame::Format_RGB24
        << QVideoFrame::Format_RGB565
        << QVideoFrame::Format_RGB555
        << QVideoFrame::Format_ARGB8565_Premultiplied
        << QVideoFrame::Format_BGRA32
        << QVideoFrame::Format_BGRA32_Premultiplied
        << QVideoFrame::Format_BGR32
        << QVideoFrame::Format_BGR24
        << QVideoFrame::Format_BGR565
        << QVideoFrame::Format_BGR555
        << QVideoFrame::Format_BGRA5658_Premultiplied
        << QVideoFrame::Format_AYUV444
        << QVideoFrame::Format_AYUV444_Premultiplied
        << QVideoFrame::Format_YUV444
        << QVideoFrame::Format_YUV420P
        << QVideoFrame::Format_YV12
        << QVideoFrame::Format_UYVY
        << QVideoFrame::Format_YUYV
        << QVideoFrame::Format_NV12
        << QVideoFrame::Format_NV21
        << QVideoFrame::Format_IMC1
        << QVideoFrame::Format_IMC2
        << QVideoFrame::Format_IMC3
        << QVideoFrame::Format_IMC4
        << QVideoFrame::Format_Y8
        << QVideoFrame::Format_Y16
        << QVideoFrame::Format_Jpeg
        << QVideoFrame::Format_CameraRaw
        << QVideoFrame::Format_AdobeDng;
}

bool FrameProbe::present(const QVideoFrame &frame)
{
    if (frame.isValid()) {
        QVideoFrame cloneFrame(frame);
        cloneFrame.map(QAbstractVideoBuffer::ReadOnly);

        QImage::Format imageFormat = QVideoFrame::imageFormatFromPixelFormat(cloneFrame.pixelFormat());

        const QImage image(cloneFrame.bits(),
                           cloneFrame.width(),
                           cloneFrame.height(),
                           imageFormat);
        emit frameAvailable(image);
        emit frameReady(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
        cloneFrame.unmap();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

init code

```
  QCamera * MyCamera= new QCamera(CameraDeviceName);
    MyCamera->setCaptureMode( QCamera::CaptureVideo );

    Label = new QLabel();
    Label->setText("Label");

    FrameProbe * VSurface = new FrameProbe();

    MyCamera->setViewfinder(VSurface);

    connect(VSurface, SIGNAL(frameAvailable(QImage)), this, SLOT(video_probed(QImage)));
    connect(VSurface, SIGNAL(frameReady(QPixmap)), this,SLOT(video_forward(QPixmap)));

    ui->gridLayout->addWidget(Label,0,0);

    MyCamera->start();
```

and slots

```
void MainWindow::video_probed(QImage InVideoFrame){

  FramesProbed++;
  std::cout<<FramesProbed<<std::endl;

}
void MainWindow::video_forward(QPixmap InVideoFrame){

    Label->setPixmap(InVideoFrame); //<<<<<<<<< Segmentation Fault here
}
```

If I change video_forward slot to something like this

```
void MainWindow::video_forward(QPixmap InVideoFrame){

    InVideoFrame.save("c:\\temp\\a.jpg",0,-1);
    QPixmap a;
    a.load("c:\\temp\\a.jpg");

    Label->setPixmap(a);
}
```

it work. Of course slow :) but work...

PS: In the FrameProbe::present image have QImage::Format_RGB32 format.

Comment: Have you tried using valgrind? It is very helpful to see exactly what resource was accessed while not allocated.

Comment: The problem is likely with implicit sharing of QPixmap internal data: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html. See video_forward function and there you have QPixmap object destroyed while leaving the function and it is shared with label. Also avoid sending objects by value as you do unless you sure. Better use const T& as Qt does if possible.

Comment: @AlexanderV yes, it was my problem. Any actions which made a real copy of the Pixmap solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
bool FrameProbe::present(const QVideoFrame &frame)
{
   ...
   emit frameAvailable(image.copy());
   ...
}

// slot video_probed
connect(VSurface, &FrameProbe::frameAvailable, [=](QImage a){
    Label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(a));
});
```

**So why crashed:**

Because you are using below to construct `QImage`:

> QImage::QImage(uchar *data, int width, int height, Format format,
>   QImageCleanupFunction cleanupFunction = Q_NULLPTR, void *cleanupInfo =
>   Q_NULLPTR)

The first param `data` is set from `cloneFrame` and it will be released after `cloneFrame.unmap();`. `data` won't exist in the `QLabel::paintEvent` stack.

Comment: Thank you! This is just sandbox, not a real application. I just separate QImage for later image processing and QPixmap for display as viewfinder in different slots.

Comment: @AbbeyRoad I see, The solution sending `image.copy()` didn't work?

Comment: image.copy() work like a charm. And any other solutions which made a real copy of data (e.g not implicit shared copy).

Comment: @AbbeyRoad `image.copy()` is copy the data of `QImage`...I didn't see other ways...

Comment: you can make something like this

    void MainWindow::video_forward(QPixmap InVideoFrame){

        InVideoFrame.setMask(InVideoFrame.mask());
        Label->setPixmap(InVideoFrame);
        Label->update();

   }

without image.copy() and it will work

Comment: @AbbeyRoad `setMask` is not `copy`... _This function merges the mask with the pixmap's alpha channel._ If you want copy pixmap, there also having the `QPixmap::copy`.

Comment: QPixmap was implicitly shared in that case. So any changes (setMask too) of a QPixmap will lead copy-on-write.